# How do detect if request was cancelled by client on ktor server

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I use ktor on server and have a request that may be executed for a long time (one minute or more). I want to detect client request cancellation to release resources and cancel the long running operation. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, got any solution to how to check this reliably on ktor 2.x?

Comment: No, migrated to spring :)